# Cannot run the website deployed by Visual Studio - GET http://localhost:8080/_configuration/MyApp 404?

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web application in Visual Studio 2019 (.Net Core 3.1, Angular, with authentication of "Individual User Accounts/Store user accounts in-app").

Then I published the application to folder `...\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\`.

Then I try to test the deployed website

1. Run `MyApp.exe` in `...\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\`.

```
PS C:\Users\.....\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish> .\MyApp.exe
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Starting IdentityServer4 version 3.0.0.0
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using explicitly configured authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\wfaaf\source\repos\MyApp2\MyApp\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish
```

2. copy and host `\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\ClientApp\dist\` in IIS.

The web page shows in Browser. However, the console shows errors?

> polyfills-es2015.0ef207fb7b4761464817.js:1 GET http://localhost:8080/_configuration/MyApp 404 (Not Found)
>
> polyfills-es2015.0ef207fb7b4761464817.js:1 GET http://localhost:8080/_configuration/MyApp 404 (Not Found)
>
> main-es2015.faf629d7395bba656bc6.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load settings for 'MyApp'
>
> main-es2015.faf629d7395bba656bc6.js:1 ERROR Error: Could not load settings for 'MyApp'
>
> main-es2015.faf629d7395bba656bc6.js:1 ERROR Error: Could not load settings for 'MyApp'

The host of `http://localhost:8080/_configuration/MyApp` should be the `https://localhost:5001`. How to set it?